# Error while deserializing Json from WCF service in MVC

Tags: java, c#, json, wcf, serialization

I call a Rest wcf service from MVC5 project. I try to serialize the Jason to send it to view but I am getting error.
this is my controller code that call the service and return the Json.

```
  public class CustomerController : Controller
{

    readonly string customerServiceUri = "http://localhost:63674/CSA.svc/";

    // GET: /Customer/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        object customerList = null;
        using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
        {
            string jsonStr;
            jsonStr = webclient.DownloadString(customerServiceUri + "GetAllCustomers");

            customerList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(jsonStr);
        }

        return View(customerList);

    }
```

the jsonStr variable has this values:

{"GetAllCustomersResult":[{"Account_Number":"7000019000415","Account_Payment_Status":null,"Account_Status":null,"Create_Date":null,"Customer_ID":9000415,"Email":null,"First_Name":"IMAD","Last4SSN":null,"LastPayment_Amount":null,"Last_Name":"KAMAR","Last_Payment_Date":null,"Modified_Date":null,"Online_Agreement":false,"Payment_in":null,"Username":null,"isActivated":false,"isActive":false,"isLocked":false,"isRegistered":false,"unsuccessful_login_count":0},

but I am getting error right in desterilizing line, this is the error:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CSAMVCCALLService.Models.Customer]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'GetAllCustomersResult', line 1, position 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is not an array or list. It is a single object. So your code should be something like this

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(jsonStr);
```

---

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Account_Number { get; set; }
    public object Account_Payment_Status { get; set; }
    public object Account_Status { get; set; }
    public object Create_Date { get; set; }
    public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
    public object Email { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public object Last4SSN { get; set; }
    public object LastPayment_Amount { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public object Last_Payment_Date { get; set; }
    public object Modified_Date { get; set; }
    public bool Online_Agreement { get; set; }
    public object Payment_in { get; set; }
    public object Username { get; set; }
    public bool isActivated { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public bool isLocked { get; set; }
    public bool isRegistered { get; set; }
    public int unsuccessful_login_count { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomersResult { get; set; }
}
```

BTW: I used http://json2csharp.com/ to create the c# classes from your json.

Comment: Thanks @EZI that was a clean answer.